# HTML Tooltip jQuery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some text, and certain words highlighted. I would like that an image (mostly gif) appears as a kind of "tooltip" when I hover over the respective text. For every word I highlight I would like to use a different gif.

If I use CSS with `a:hover` and `background-image`, the whole layout gets messed up. I also tried jQuery & qTip, but I did not find a solution for the images.

The most perfect solution would be if I could:

```
<a href="#" title="" src="1y2m_small.png">1st year, 2nd month</a>
```

Where `src` is the image I would like to appear in the tooltip.

Comment: more info required code etc would help

Comment: You said you tried some plugins? What were the results? if you post your code and the errors we could help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a little jQuery:

```
$('a').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children('img').remove();
    }
);
```

CSS required:

```
a{
    position: relative;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0; //position how you want
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8wb9P/) is a working jsFiddle

**Source(s)**

[.hover() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Thank you very much! But it seems I just don't get it: http://jsfiddle.net/KysWc/3/

Comment: look at [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wb9P/)

Comment: The random CSS I used before was pushing the image off the screen..

Comment: You are awesome. Just saying. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thanks and no worries. Just remember to use a more specific selector in the script if you need to

Comment: Dear Billy, is there any chance this might work for a youtube video that will start automatically upon hover?
How would one need to adjust the JS part, so a youtube-video might work? I understand I need a special selector for that, but how to implement the youtube part? (If this is not too comlicated for you tu explain)

Comment: You could append the embed code from youtube (under share on any video) instead of the img? Just put the embed code in the quotes in `.append`

Comment: Funny! Every time I hover, a new iframe is added below the text :)

Comment: Yes - and don't forget to change the 'img' in the remove function to iframe! Is this the result you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Got your answer right here son. Check me and +1 me please

http://jsfiddle.net/alaingoldman/ybQCd/4/

simple

CSS

> #hide{
>      display:none;
>      position:absolute;
>   }

HTML

> ```
> <span id="target" > Hover over me </span>
> <img id="hide"  src="http://oi45.tinypic.com/33tjd3d.jpg">
> ```

jQuery

> $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
>       $('#hide').css({
>          left:  e.pageX + 20,
>          top:   e.pageY
>       });
>       $("#target").hover(
>          function () {
>             $("#hide").show();
>       },
>          function () {
>             $("#hide").hide();
>       });});

Comment: That feeling you get when you answer a stackoverflow question perfectly but not one +1's it or checkmarks it :(

Comment: This isn't exactly 'perfect'

Comment: you should use a class of hide, not an id, and you js is very illegible. and maybe provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: there is a jsfiddle example where you can read the JS
Did you read my post before commenting or was that too much reading for you.

Comment: Sorry but the jsfiddle wasn't there before, and your JS is still indented incorrectly. I don't see anything wrong with my code. & I was only trying to help you by pointing out *why*you post wasn't marked as correct and *why* it wasn't perfect. There's no need to be rude.